# Issue with MS SQL Job Target Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-job

I have been working on creating a sql job in one server(ABC) which will update a table in another server(XYZ). But its not updating the target server. When I manually run from target server, its working. I have added target server as below (note: this is the value in job script)

```
msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'XYZ'
```

Below is the query of sql job which will update the database table in XYZ server.

```
  USE [msdb]
GO


BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Multi-Server)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'MULTI-SERVER', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Multi-Server)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Clear Test Data', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'Clear Test Data', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Multi-Server)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Is Primary?', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=4, 
        @on_success_step_id=2, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'UPDATE dbo.Ping
SET Live = 1', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=4
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Clear Test Data', 
        @step_id=2, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'EXEC [dbo].[spClearTestData]', 
        @database_name=N'DB1', 
        @flags=4
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'Schedule', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=4, 
        @freq_subday_interval=10, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
        @active_start_date=20190214, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=10000, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'ed2ce0c6-f2c1-4bf7-8b6c-de48e5dcfead'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'XYZ'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

Comment: This script creates a job, is the job being executed at any time? Any error messages?

Comment: @EzLo, there is no error message in history. I have ran it manually. still no luck.

Comment: the account that the SQL Agent runs under, does it have the necessary permissions to the other server?

Comment: @Greg, I had the same doubt but how to verify that?

Comment: Log into sql using that account and try executing the same query

Comment: You are using an MSX environment and want to deploy this script to the target from the master? If it isn't running or doesn't deploy it is most likely because of permission issues. I have had success after going to the target and opening the SQL agent then select 'Add target', the associated jobs will give the correct permissions.